# Is there Path Edit Control in Win32?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, winapi

I would like to add an edit box (or is it a combo box?) for entering a file-path using Visual C Win32 so that it offers auto-complete - the same as when you type in Windows Explorer's address bar.

Is there a common control or property I'm missing that allows me to do that?

Comment: for pure win32, you'll have to use combo box and implement the feature on your on. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773169(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @JosephH No you won't. The shell offers such services for you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the standard edit control and call [`SHAutoComplete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759862%28VS.85%29.aspx). Like this:

```
SHAutoComplete(editWnd, SHACF_DEFAULT);
```

The system will do the rest for you.

Comment: This is so simple works really well in my test app, but when I put it in the main application SHAutoComplete return E_NOINTERFACE - Any idea why that might be? Is that because my (already existing) CoInitialize calls are multithreaded or something?

Comment: User interface APIs generally require single-threaded apartments. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287087

Answer (score 3):

There is no Common Control for that. What you can do, however, is use a standard Edit control and attach the IAutoComplete interface to it, which can be configured to use the file system (amongst other things) as a source for getting string values from. The easiest way to do that is to call the SHAutoComplete function.